# Query DNS server for usable/plain IP address

Tags: python, dns

I am trying to write a program to query multiple DNS servers for the IP address of a hostname. My only problem is that I can't get the actual IP address, only the server's response.

This is my code:

```
import dns.resolver

my_resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()

reply_list = []
dns_list = ['8.8.8.8', '8.8.4.4', '1.2.3.4']
resp = []

for server in dns_list:
    try:
        my_resolver.nameservers = [server]
        answer = my_resolver.resolve('google.com')
        print(answer.response)
    except dns.resolver.LifetimeTimeout:
        print('Error')
```

I don't understand how I can use the output.
I had hoped for a list, a dict or a tuple as a response.

But I get this on the console:

```
id 54769
opcode QUERY
rcode NOERROR
flags QR RD RA
;QUESTION
google.com. IN A
;ANSWER
google.com. 233 IN A 172.217.16.206
;AUTHORITY
;ADDITIONAL
id 39642
opcode QUERY
rcode NOERROR
flags QR RD RA
;QUESTION
google.com. IN A
;ANSWER
google.com. 300 IN A 172.217.18.14
;AUTHORITY
;ADDITIONAL
Error

Process finished with exit code 0`
```

Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`answer.response` contains the actual DNS protocol response from the server. Instead, you can use `str(answer)` to get the resolved IP address instead. Like this:

```
import dns.resolver

server_list = ['8.8.8.8', '8.8.4.4']
records = []

dns.resolver.default_resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver(configure=False)

for serv in server_list:
    dns.resolver.default_resolver.nameservers = [serv]
    answers = dns.resolver.resolve('google.com')
    records.extend([str(answer) for answer in answers])

print(records)  # => ['172.217.1.110', '142.250.191.142']
```

Comment: However you should first always check 1) for the return code (if error or not) and 2) then only look at records, but without any preconceptions on what you got specially the record type that you should test (because you can ask for `A` for example but get a `CNAME` back).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help!
This is what I ended up doing to get a list with dicts back.
With the DNS server as the key and the result (IP-Address) as value.
Even though I still don't understand how that server response seemingly "magically" gets turned into the plain IP-Address.
Any resource for that is appreciated! :)

```
import dns.resolver

my_resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()

reply_list = []
dns_list = ['8.8.8.8', '8.8.4.4', '1.2.3.4']
records_dict_list = []
resp = []

for server in dns_list:
    try:
        my_resolver.nameservers = [server]
        answers = my_resolver.resolve('google.com', 'A')
        records_dict_list.append({str(server): str(answer) for answer in answers})
    except dns.resolver.LifetimeTimeout:
        records_dict_list.append({str(server): 'error'})
print(records_dict_list)
```

Outputs:

```
[{'8.8.8.8': '142.250.186.78'}, {'8.8.4.4': '172.217.16.206'}, {'1.2.3.4': 'error'}]

Process finished with exit code 0
```